# Was Mesalim King of Kish, the same person as Moses king of Kush?

Tags: hebrew-bible, moses, egypt, eden, babylon

**Mesilim**

[Mesilim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesilim)

> Mesilim (Sumerian: ),[3] also spelled Mesalim (c. 2600 BC), was lugal (king) of the Sumerian city-state of Kish.

> Though his name is missing from the Sumerian king list, Mesilim is among the earliest historical figures recorded in archaeological documents. He reigned some time in the "Early Dynastic III" period (c. 2500–2330 BC). Inscriptions from his reign state that he sponsored temple constructions in both Adab and Lagash, where he apparently enjoyed some suzerainty.[4] He is also known from a number of fragments

**Moses**

[Moses king of Cush](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332979868_MOSES_IN_CUSH_DEVELOPMENT_OF_THE_LEGEND)

**Summary**

So Moses is connected to Cush/Kush.

And there was a factual historical and archaeological king of Kish from Mesopotamia in 2600bc, named Mesilim.
He is not in historical records, however arachaeological excavations have found that the kingship of Kish pre-dates historical records, and that the first king of Kish was likely Mesilim.

I can find nowhere however, archaeologists nor historians making the connection between the kingdom of Kish, and Kingdom of Kush

Comment: I do not think this question is even a question about the Bible.  It should be closed to moved to a history site.  See https://history.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Dottard I will get nothing but abuse and ridicule if i mention Moses on a history site. On the otherhand. I may get abuse and ridicule mentioning Mesilim on a biblical site. Is there anywhere that deals with half bible half history questions like this, academically, professionally, and unemotionally?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the History stack exchange

Comment: It will not be answered here.  I understand your concern.  Historians agree that Moses was a real figure but disagree about who and when he existed and whether he wrote what Jews and Christians say he wrote.  However, this site will only entertain a question about a specific Bible passage.

Comment: @Dottard I see. Apologies. I have certain members of my family that are born again christians. But i am neither a believer nor disbeliever. I am not an expert on biblical matters, so i did not realise that this was not the correct department to ask this. Many apologies and thank you for your polite responses. I will vote to close aswell

Comment: Thanks for you understanding.  BTW - it is an excellent question!!

Comment: I am also voting to close. If you can find a text or two in scripture to sensibly link this to, I will retract my close vote. At the moment, I confess I do not really understand the question, myself. (My aged mind only functions properly within the realm of scripture, these days.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well they lived about a thousand years apart so I would guess not.

One might have been a shadow or image of the other.  An "icon" or "kohen" of the other.

(And you don't have to be either theist or atheist because it isn't one dimensional)

Comment: That is more likely. Most likely somekind of connection. But Moses certainly was not Mesilim, upon deeper research. As you say, entirely different time periods completely